# tampermonkey disable function on targeted site

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

How to disable javascript function before it will run with tampermonkey, here the some example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
+function() {
    function test1() {
        alert('test1');
    }
    function test2() {
        alert('test2');
    }
    function test3() {
        alert('test3');
    }
    test1();
    test2(); // how to disable this function to execute?
    test3();
}();
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

What javascript code can disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tampermonkey userscripts can't influence an embedded `<script>` element directly.

You can try spoofing the built-in javascript function used by that script. But Tampermonkey takes some time to inject the userscript so HEAD-embedded page scripts may execute first.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name    Spoof alert()
// @run-at  document-start
// @grant   unsafeWindow
// ==/UserScript==

unsafeWindow.alert = function(){};
```